# Send, SendInput, SendEvent functions entering single key multiple times

Tags: autohotkey

I have created a script in AutoHotKey.I have to Enter the entire file path to be opened in the 
file browser.i have used send function but it passes the same keys multiple times. I tried using the function SetKeyDelay but still it enters the keys multiple times. I tried other alternatives as sendInput and SendEvent but still it didnt work. 
Even if i terminate the script in between and if the control switches to some Input box or Editor, it starts entering the values into that area. Send function keeps on entering the keys even after the script execution is terminated.

Script:

```
;Open Adobe Acrobat 8. 
run Acrobat.exe sleep, 1000 

WinWait, Adobe Acrobat Professional, 
Sleep, 1000 

;Open Compare Documents Window 
send, {ALT}A 

Sleep, 1000 

send, U 

WinWait, Compare Documents, 

;Enter File Path 
IfWinNotActive, Compare Documents, 
WinActivate, Compare Documents, 
WinWaitActive, Compare Documents, 
Sleep, 1000 

send, !H 

WinWaitActive, Open,,1000 
sleep, 1000 

SendEvent, "D:\Sample\a.pdf"
```

It Enters text something like this

CCCC:::::\\DDDDiiiiii

Comment: Please provide your script.

Comment: More tags, please. What language are we talking about for example.

Comment: Site: www.autohotkey.com 
The sample script which i have written is as follows:                                                                         

;Open Adobe Acrobat 8.
 run Acrobat.exe
 sleep, 1000
 WinWait, Adobe Acrobat Professional, 
 Sleep, 1000

;Open Compare Documents Window 
  send, {ALT}A 
  Sleep, 1000
  send, U 
  WinWait, Compare Documents, 

;Enter File Path
  IfWinNotActive, Compare Documents, 
  WinActivate, Compare Documents, 
  WinWaitActive, Compare Documents, 
  Sleep, 1000
  send, !H
  WinWaitActive, Open,,1000
  sleep, 1000
  SendEvent, "D:\Sample\a.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

Update AutoHotkey to the latest version.

Don't use `SendEvent`. It allows other input to interrupt the text as it is being entered. Use SendInput instead. It is recommended to put the following at the top of all your scripts:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
```

`SendMode Input` changes `Send` to use `SendInput` instead of `SendEvent`. It buffers the input and sends it all at once instead of letting other keyboard/scripts interrupt the text. See: [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendEvent) for more information.

Restart your computer and make sure that there are no other AutoHotkey programs running, or that there isn't multiple instances of your Autohotkey script running. This is especially a problem when testing, as you might have launched the same script multiple times, and if the thread hasn't been properly terminated, you may have multiple instances there waiting for the Open window to be activated. Once the Open window has been activated, then you may have 4+ dormant scripts all trying to type at the same time, which would give you the output that you are describing.